# Returning Firestore Query If Nothing Is Found In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to console.log "Not Found" if a search query in Firestore isn't found.
At the moment I am using the following to perform the query which looks through all documents for an email = "123@test.com".

This works fine if the document contains what I am searching for but I cant get it to console.log anything if nothing is found

```
db.collection("test").where('email', '==', "123@test.com").get()

        .then(function (querySnapshot) {

            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                console.log(doc.data())
            });

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no matching document is found then the `empty` property of the [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot) will be `true`:

```
db.collection("test").where('email', '==', "123@test.com").get().then(qSnap => {
  if (qSnap.empty) {
    console.log("Not found")
  } else {
    // proceed
  }
})
```

Comment: That has worked great and thank you for linking to the QuerySnapshot documentation which is something I have to say I overlooked.